# Add columns to SQL query output

Tags: sql

I have searched this site and others, and I am unable to find a clear answer, so here I am. In the below query, I will get an output with a single column for the county. What I would like to do can only be described in Excel parlance as transpose the counties so each county for a brand family is in its own column. I have played around with using pivot, but unfortunately do not fully grasp what would be required. This is not my first query, but I am relatively new to SQL scripting, so please ask any clarification questions and I will do my best to answer.

Some of the brand families have 10 counties and some have 20, so some of the columns would be blank. This is for an in-house DB, not the SO DB, running on SQL Server 2008R2, FWIW.

The script is:

```
select distinct b.reckey as BrandFamilyKey, b.recname as BrandFamilyName,
       g.recname as County
from territories as t 
left join dbo.TerritoryBrandFamilies as tbf on tbf.TerritoryNid = t.TerritoryNid 
left join Customers as c on c.TerritoryNid = t.TerritoryNid 
left join GeographicAreas as g on g.GeoAreaNid = c.GeoAreaNid
left join brandfamilies as b on b.brandfamilynid = tbf.brandfamilynid

where t.activeflag = 1 AND C.GeoAreaNid IS NOT NULL and b.activeflag = 1

order by b.RecName,g.recname
```

the output would look like

```
brand family 1     county 1
brand family 1     county 2
brand family 1     county 3
```

What I would like to see is:

```
brand family 1     county 1     county 2     county 3
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using and also explain how you want to hand the fourth county.

Comment: @GurV You keep making your screen name shorter :-)